# How do I make a api call with functional components?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am using the following component:

```
export const Home =() =>
        <div className="cardBox" style={styleBox}>
            <CardTrail></CardTrail>
            <CardTrail></CardTrail>
            <CardTrail></CardTrail>
            <Footer></Footer>
          </div>
```

and I am was trying to make a get API request using AJAX. Cant find a suitable way to do it with functional components. I achieved it with class components via the help of componentDidMount() lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in a functional component if using React 16.8 or higher is to use an effect with an empty dependency list:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  // ajax call here
}, [])
```